# Unable to set device connection state as INPUT device type is none

Tags: android, audio

Android 14: D/UsbAlsaDevice( 1571): Unable to set device connection state as INPUT device type is none

its from logcat, when I connect DAC or digital earphone. It appears in some aosp roms. I found nothing useful about this log before. I'm sure DAC is not broke, system can connect it but no sound output. Music software can use USB exclusive mode to output sound normally.
By the way, dac always works well in official rom (MIUI).

I try to flash other roms, it works in some roms. magisk modules, like Dolby driver and viper drivers, are not help, maybe I haven't found the right one.
I want to fix it in the aosp roms which didn't work well with dac. It has been bothering me for a long time.

info:
device: Redmi Note 11 4G (selene)
soc: mt6768H (G88)
DAC: TTGK cx31993